# USB devices are greyed out in VirtualBox

Tags: usb, virtualbox, windows

I'm running Windows XP on Virtual Box. I'm trying to write to a USB pen drive. VirtualBox detect the pen drive but its name is greyed our in GUI. And I couldn't pick it from the list. How can I use this pen drive with the virtual machine?

[image: USB device greyed out]

Answer (score 12):

I found the solution myself. All I need was to eject usb pen drive from mac's desktop. When the drive ejected, it became available in VirtualBox.

Comment: worked for me as well, VB 5.0.20 r106931 running win10

Answer (score 0):

I had to eject my USB from the **host** OS (macOS) but I was also using a USB 3.0 so I had to:

1. stop my VM
2. select my VM from the master list
3. Go to Setting > Setting > Ports > USB > USB 3.0
4. Add my USB

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it is grayed out is because it is in use by the host system. To be able to use it you need to:

1. Eject the USB from the host system.
2. Restart the VM
3. Add the USB